# How to do a WHERE for two tables using Bookshelf JS

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I have two tables **users** and **accounts** (*users.id = accounts.id*), I want to do a login that can be accessed from both tables, users.username OR accounts.mail

I'm using BookShelf JS, and I've already tried different ways to condition if users.username = identification doesn't exist, then check account.mail = identification and none of them work

```
//This code obtains the desired result but only when given the username.
            return UserModel.query((qb) => {
                qb.where('username', identification)
                //.orWhere('account.mail', identification) Something Like This!
            })

            .fetch({
                withRelated: [{ 'account': (qb) => { qb.column('id', 'mail', 'password') } }],
                columns: ['id', 'username']
            })
```

So if users.username is given then users.id and account.id will be given, also if I give account.mail then account.id and users.id will be given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to implement join this way.

```
import UserModel from './UserModel';

        UserModel.query((qb) => {
            qb.select('users.id as userid','users.username', 'accounts.id as accountid', 'accounts.mail','accounts.password')
            .where('users.username', identification)
            .orWhere('accounts.mail', identification)
            .leftJoin('accounts','users.id','accounts.id')
        })
        .fetch()
        .then(function (details){
           return res.json({ message: "Successfull.", data: details });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return res.json({ message: error.message });
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative, it's working though, if someone has any better approach I'm open to accept suggestions:

```js
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        {
            if(identification == null || password == null) return reject(new Error('invalid_parameters'));

            return UserModel.query((qb) => {
                qb.where('username', identification)
            })

            .fetch({
                withRelated: [{ 'account': (qb) => { qb.column('id', 'mail', 'password') } }],
                columns: ['id', 'username']
            })

            .then((result) =>
            {
                if(result != null)
                {
                    result = result.toJSON();

                    return resolve({id: result.id, username: result.username});
                }

                return AccountModel.query((qb) => {
                    qb.where('mail', identification)
                })
                .fetch({
                    withRelated: [{ 'user': (qb) => { qb.column('id', 'username') } }],
                    columns: ['id', 'mail', 'password']
                })
            })

            .then((result) =>
            {
                if(result == null) return reject(new Error('invalid_login'));

                result = result.toJSON();

                return resolve({id: result.id, username: result.user.username});
            })

            .catch((err) =>
            {
                return reject(err);
            });
        });
```

What I did was just to check if the result was not null, if not null, then resolve with the right credentials, else if result is null then check the other model (AccountModel) and if that is also null then reject, otherwise then resolve with the right credentials